# JavaScript libraries fail to load sometimes and sometimes they load properly, no issues on Server side

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a strange issue. I have this server side application, and uses jquery, bootstrap and jq libraries.

Most of the times, I mean 80% of the times, the application works fine, and all the libraries are loaded properly, but then sometimes I face this issue. Strange thing is this issue does not persists for long.

Checked server side logs as well, no issues that side.

As per chrome console,

[Error Image in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLIwb.png)

Besides, in a span of 2-3 minutes, when it was happening on constant refreshes, I checked the server nodes, there weren't any issues. Also, these are not all the files. These are only few of the files which were showing errors, rest of the library files in the same directory were loading correctly.

Comment: Is this your server that's hosting those? Because I can see some 503s in that console. Switch to the network tab and see what error codes you get there for the requests. It's likely to be something to do with the server.

Comment: On top of @vlaz 's comment - try loading the libraries with CDNs and see if you still get errors. If not, it's 100% server-related.

Comment: @vlaz yes it is the server which is hosting it.

Comment: @vlaz Besides, in a span of 2-3 minutes, when it was happening on constant refresh, I checked the server nodes and everything, there weren't any issues. Also, these are not all the files. These are only few of the files which were showing errors, rest of the library files were loading correctly.

Comment: Still, it'd be useful to know why the browser thinks it can't load the resources. If it's a 404 it won't be able to find them, if it's a 403, it won't be allowed to, if it's a 500, it's the server claiming it's broken and so on.

Comment: Even the cross domain requests is occurring successfully, since it is using https protocol. Don't know why server has gone berserk. We have checked logs constantly for many days. Could it be an issue with folder structure or directory being hosted on server? But the next question pops up, why isn't it consistent in that case. And 80% of the services work fine and rest fail.

Comment: Why not consistent - I don't know. It seems that you're saying that when the issue shows up, it's persistent for a while. This indicates that _something_ along the request chain is broken. It could be a DNS server cacheing the wrong thing for a while (though, it's not likely), it might be a router or something refusing to pass traffic to the server, it might be a firewall triggering and treating requests as an attack, so traffic gets blocked, it might be some server resource being depleted - e.g., memory or handles (presumably due to a leak) until they get released and so on.

Comment: @vlaz yes you are correct, but in such cases, all the service calls or requests should be blocked, but that doesn't happen. Its like half of the page loads properly i.e. response is found and rest half of the service calls show these issues in the browser console.

Comment: @vlaz I checked the entire request chain. I didn't find any issue. When this  issue came up, the legacy services were working fine but the new ones were not including this one.